Does anyone know why my variable (x) changed its value from 3 to 0 (1 after x++) in this program? I'm trying to make a signup system but it overwrites
Like what the title said, I was trying to make a signup system but for some reason it overwrites the array which was supposed to be defaultuser[0] = "12291955" it becomes what I inputted except I wanted it to go to defaultuser[3] (denoted by x = 3). So basically, the signup system is supposed to add a 4th user. (The following is a header file for my main.c file)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void loginsystem(){
    char defaultuser[][100] = {"12291995", "12221999", "12241344"};
    char defaultpass[][100] = {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
  

    int i = 0, indicator = 1, x = 3;
    char userinput[20], passinput[20], choicest[20], prog[20]; 
    const char* choicecmp;
    system("cls");
    printf("\nSystem");
    printf("\nWould you like to create an account or log into an existing account? (Type Signup or Login) ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", choicest);
    printf("%d", x); //x=3
    choicecmp = strlwr(choicest);
    if(strcmp(choicecmp, "signup")==0 || strcmp(choicecmp, "sign up") == 0 )
    {
        //system("cls"); 
        printf("\nEnter your ID Number: ");
        scanf(" %s", defaultuser[x]);
        printf("\nEnter your password: ");
        scanf(" %s", defaultpass[x]);
   
        getch();
        choicecmp = "login";
        x++; 
        printf("%d", x); //x becomes 1 for some reason
        getch();
    }
    if(strcmp(choicecmp, "login")==0 || strcmp(choicecmp, "log in") == 0 ){
    do{
    system("cls");
    printf("\nPlease login!");
    printf("\n\nUsername (ID Number): ");
    scanf(" %s", &userinput);
    printf("\nPassword: ");
    do{
            passinput[i] = getch();
            if(passinput[i] != '\r')
            printf("*");
            i++;
        }while(passinput[i-1] != '\r');
        passinput[i-1] = '\0';

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){ 
    if(strcmp(userinput, defaultuser[i]) == 0 && strcmp(passinput, defaultpass[i]) == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        indicator = 0;
        printf("\nWelcome back User");
    }}
    return ;
}

I tried debugging the code and turns out that int x = 3 became x=0 along the way in the signup system, and became 1 after the x++.

First of all you need to minimize your code, to isolate the problem by creating a [mre]. And while you're doing that, also make sure your code is consistently indented and readable.

As a hint though, you're probably going out of bounds of one of your arrays.

You did not demonstrate the problem, as that requires inputs that can be entered to reproduce the problem. Please provide!

On a different note, there's no such scanf format as %[]s. The s is not part of the format, and instead makes the code wait for you to input an actual s as input.

Also on a different note, don't write large pieces of code all at once. That will make it much harder to test and debug. Instead start with an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors. When it builds cleanly, test the program in all possible ways, with valid and invalid input, etc. Only then add more code, a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines.

Tip: Rather than having an array for each field (which I call "parallel arrays"), you might find it more convenient to have a single array of a struct.

Arrays are not resizable in C, meaning its size is defined at declaration, in your case you are creating arrays with 3 items each, and that means that the array was automatically declared to fit exactly 3 items, so there is no space to add a 4th item.

defaultuser has three elements.
char defaultuser[][100] = {"12291995", "12221999", "12241344"};

But you try to write to the fourth element.
int x = 3;
scanf(" %s", defaultuser[x]);

This is undefined behaviour.
